# How to detect identical part(s) inside string?

Tags: python, ruby, pattern-matching, string-matching

I try to break down the [decoding algorithm wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711961/decoding-algorithm-wanted) question into smaller questions. This is Part I.

Question:

- two strings: s1 and s2
- part of s1 is identical to part of s2
- space is separator
- how to extract the identical part(s)?

example 1:

```
s1 = "12 November 2010 - 1 visitor"
s2 = "6 July 2010 - 100 visitors"

the identical parts are "2010", "-", "1" and "visitor"
```

example 2:

```
s1 = "Welcome, John!"
s2 = "Welcome, Peter!"

the identical parts are "Welcome," and "!"
```

example 3: (to clarify the "!" example)

```
s1 = "Welcome, Sam!"
s2 = "Welcome, Tom!"

the identical parts are "Welcome," and "m!"
```

Python and Ruby preferred. Thanks

Comment: why "1" is identical in first example?

Comment: "1" is same as the first char of "100", it's similar to "visitor" is part of "visitors"

Comment: In my mind 1 and 100 are anything but identical. Can you be exact in defining what you mean by "identical"

Comment: Do the identical pieces have to be in the same corresponding "words"?  For example, if `s1 = "2010"` and `s2 = "something else 2010"`, is `2010` still an "identical part" or not?

Comment: identical: sub-string of a string is exactly equal to sub-string of another string

Comment: @S.Mark no, he's considering the single characters, not the words.

Comment: for second example commas are not idential?

Comment: @Paul Stephenson, let me use a smaller example, s1 = "12345 67890", s2 = "234 6a"; first we break s1 into ["12345", "67890"] s2 into ["234", "6a"]; then we try to match any sub-strings of strings in s1 to any sub-strings of strings in s2; so "234" is inside "12345"; sub-string of "6a" i.e. "6" matches sub-string of "67890", i.e. "6".

Comment: @S.Mark, comma is identical, see "Welcome," - comma follows "Welcome"

Comment: If `s1 = "12345 67890"` and `s2 = "6a 234"` (swapping the two "words" `6a` and `234`), are the matches still `"234"` and `"6"`?

Comment: @Paul Stephenson, If s1 = "12345 67890" and s2 = "6a 234" ... no. sub-string order is counted/significant. This example will match "6" only.

Comment: Why doesn't the "1" in "12 November" match the "1" in "6 July 2010"? Why doesn't the "2" in "12 November" match the "2" in "6 July 2010"? This is not a well-formed question yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updated this example to work with all the examples, including #1:

```
def scan(s1, s2):
    # Find the longest match where s1 starts with s2
    # Returns None if no matches
    l = len(s1)
    while 1:
        if not l:
            return None
        elif s1[:l] == s2[:l]:
            return s1[:l]
        else:
            l -= 1

def contains(s1, s2):
    D = {} # Remove duplicates using a dict
    L1 = s1.split(' ')
    L2 = s2.split(' ')

    # Don't add results which have already 
    # been processed to satisfy example #1!
    DProcessed = {}

    for x in L1:
        yy = 0
        for y in L2:
            if yy in DProcessed:
                yy += 1
                continue

            # Scan from the start to the end of the words
            a = scan(x, y)
            if a: 
                DProcessed[yy] = None
                D[a] = None
                break

            # Scan from the end to the start of the words
            a = scan(x[::-1], y[::-1])
            if a: 
                DProcessed[yy] = None
                D[a[::-1]] = None
                break
            yy += 1

    return list(D.keys())

print contains("12 November 2010 - 1 visitor",
               "6 July 2010 - 100 visitors")
print contains("Welcome, John!",
               "Welcome, Peter!")
print contains("Welcome, Sam!",
               "Welcome, Tom!")
```

Which outputs:

```
['1', 'visitor', '-', '2010']
['Welcome,', '!']
['Welcome,', 'm!']
```

Answer (score 3):

For example 1

```
>>> s1 = 'November 2010 - 1 visitor'
>>> s2 = '6 July 2010 - 100 visitors'
>>> 
>>> [i for i in s1.split() if any(j for j in s2.split() if i in j)]
['2010', '-', '1', 'visitor']
>>>
```

For both

```
>>> s1 = "Welcome, John!"
>>> s2 = "Welcome, Peter!"
>>> [i for i in s1.replace('!',' !').split() if any(j for j in s2.replace('!',' !').split() if i in j)]
['Welcome,', '!']
>>>
```

**Note**: Above codes will not work for example 3, which is OP just added

Comment: This doesn't get `!` in the second example though, since (I think) the questioner wants any substring in s1 to match any substring in s2 (not including spaces).

Comment: @clyfe, I've changed `.startswith` to `in` to support that.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, why replace('!', " !") is needed?

Comment: @Horace, Its because split method need whitespace to split it.

Comment: @S.Mark, please check example 3

Comment: looks like example 3 completely fails for all of our answers. I will update it soon.

Comment: Since, David already done that, I stop coding on this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = "12 November 2010 - 1 visitor"
s2 = "6 July 2010 - 100 visitors"
l1 = s1.split()
for item in l1:
   if item in s2:
      print item
```

This splits on whitespace.

A solution that also splits on word boundaries (in order to catch the `!` in example 2) doesn't work in Python because `re.split()` won't split on zero-length matches.

The third example, making even any substring of the words a potential match, is making things a lot more complicated because of the many possible variations (for `1234`, I'd have to check against `1234`, `123`, `234`, `12`, `23`, `34`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, and with each extra digit, the number of permutations increases exponentially.

Comment: I think the question wants to split on "anything" (i.e., any substring that doesn't include punctuation is a possible match)

Answer (score 1):

The complete Ruby solution:

```
def start_similar(i, j)
    front = ''
    for ix in (0...([i.size, j.size].min))
      if i[ix] == j[ix] then
        front += i[ix].chr
      else
        break
      end
    end
    return front
end

def back_similar(i, j)
    back = ''
    for ix in (0...([i.size, j.size].min)).to_a.reverse
      dif = i.size < j.size ? j.size - i.size : i.size - j.size
      ci = i[ i.size < j.size ? ix : ix + dif ]
      cj = j[ i.size > j.size ? ix : ix + dif ]
      if ci == cj then
        back = ci.chr + back
      else
        break
      end
    end
    return back
end

def scan(x, y)
    a, b = x.split(' '), y.split(' ')
    result = []
    for i in a do
      for j in b do
        result << start_similar(i, j)
        result << back_similar(i, j)
      end
    end
    return result.uniq.select do |r| not r.empty? end
end

puts scan(
    "12 November 2010 - 1 visitor",
    "6 July 2010 - 100 visitors"
).inspect
# ["1", "2010", "0", "-", "visitor"]

puts scan(
    "Welcome, John!",
    "Welcome, Peter!"
).inspect
# ["Welcome,", "!"]

puts scan(
    "Welcome, Sam!",
    "Welcome, Tom!"
).inspect
# ["Welcome,", "m!"]
```